# Add another repository to maven sub module

Tags: maven, repository

Can another repository be added to a maven sub module?

I added a repository in the sub module pom using the `<repositories>` and `<repository>` tags, because I don't have access to the parent pom where the main repository is defined.

I added a dependency on an artifact in the new repository, but it is not found, indicated by my IDE, and when doing a maven build the output is that the artifact is not found in the main repository.

Can an additional repository be added to a maven sub module?

Comment: Do you use a repository manager ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes I do - Nexus.